# How to write files in different directories based on different spring-profiles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-properties

I generate a Zip File in my code and now i want to weite it in a directory

```
/export
```

in Production then I want to write it in

```
/foo/bar
```

I already got 2 Profiles (it & Production):

```
application-it.yaml
application-production.yaml
```

But how do I manage two save locations in my code now or what propertie should I use for that?

Comment: have you tried configuring the path in the properties file and using the config in the code that generates the zip file?

Comment: thats the question. what variable should I use in the properties File? Or can I just declare a variable in the properties file and call it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Boot you can do it like this.

'application-it.yml' content:

```
file.storage: "/export"
```

'application-production.yml' content:

```
file.storage: "/foo/bar"
```

I don't know your real implementation. But imagine that you use service to process the file. Then you can include @Value to your service to include specific variable.
My 'SimpleService.java' content:

```
package test.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

@Service
public class SimpleService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleService.class);

    @Value("${file.storage}")
    private String fileStorage;

    public void saveFile() throws IOException {
        LOG.info("Folder to store files: {}", fileStorage);

        File file = new File(fileStorage + File.separatorChar + "test.zip");
        ZipOutputStream outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("entry.txt");
        outputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
        outputStream.write("test".getBytes());
        outputStream.closeEntry();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

And finally, when you start your app (in my case with Maven) specify active app profile:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=it
```

or

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=production
```

Comment: Perfect answer! exactly what I needed. Thanks Stargazer. I would vote it up but my Reputation is not high enough.